# MongoDB create product summary collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a product collection like this:

```
{
"_id": "5a74784a8145fa1368905373",
"name": "This is my first product",
"description": "This is the description of my first product",
"category": "34/73/80",
"condition": "New",
"images": [
    {
        "length": 1000,
        "width": 1000,
        "src": "products/images/firstproduct_image1.jpg"
    },
    ...
],

"attributes": [
    {
        "name": "Material",
        "value": "Synthetic"
    },
    ...
],

"variation": {
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Color",
            "values": ["Black", "White"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "values": ["S", "M", "L"]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

and a variation collection like this:

```
{
"_id": "5a748766f5eef50e10bc98a8",
"name": "color:black,size:s",
"productID": "5a74784a8145fa1368905373",
"condition": "New",
"price": 1000,
"sale": null,
"image": [
    {
        "length": 1000,
        "width": 1000,
        "src": "products/images/firstvariation_image1.jpg"
    }
],
"attributes": [
    {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "Black"
    },
    {
        "name": "Size",
        "value": "S"
    }
]
}
```

I want to keep the documents separate and for the purpose of easy browsing, searching and faceted search implementation, I want to fetch all the data in a single query but I don't want to do join in my application code.
I know it's achievable using a third collection called summary that might look like this:

```
{
"_id": "5a74875fa1368905373",
"name": "This is my first product",
"category": "34/73/80",
"condition": "New",
"price": 1000,
"sale": null,
"description": "This is the description of my first product",
"images": [
    {
        "length": 1000,
        "width": 1000,
        "src": "products/images/firstproduct_image1.jpg"
    },
    ...
],

"attributes": [
    {
        "name": "Material",
        "value": "Synthetic"
    },
    ...
],

"variations": [
    {
        "condition": "New",
        "price": 1000,
        "sale": null,
        "image": [
            {
                "length": 1000,
                "width": 1000,
                "src": "products/images/firstvariation_image.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "attributes": [
            "color=black",
            "size=s"
        ]
    },
    ...
]
}
```

problem is, I don't know how to keep the summary collection in sync with the product and variation collection. I know it can be done using mongo-connector but i'm not sure how to implement it.
please help me, I'm still a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually need to maintain a summary collection, its redundant to store product and variation summary in another collection

instead of you can use an aggregate pipeline **$lookup** to outer join product and variation using productID

aggregate pipeline

```
db.products.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup : {
                from : "variation",
                localField : "_id",
                foreignField : "productID",
                as : "variations"
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

Comment: thank you, your answer helps... but what if i want to maintain that summary collection anyway like mentioned here: https://dzone.com/articles/product-catalog-part-1-schema.

Comment: @s.frz, dude did you find any way of keeping summary document sync with other collecitons ? I am looking forward for your help.